# Invoke chromecast media router outside an activity

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I'm exposing Chromecast sdk to a library that can be consumed in react native.

So, when I run

```
VideoCastManager.initialize(mCurrentActivity, options);
mCastManager = VideoCastManager.getInstance();
mCastManager.startCastDiscovery();
```

Inside the main activity, it works great. But if I do it from a class, It crashed with

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The media router service must only be
>   accessed on the application's main thread.

But I need a way to invoke the startDiscovery method outside the activity, as it will be called from another action, and it will be broadcasting if it found a chromecast or not.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What type of Context do you have?

Comment: @AliNaddaf it is from type ReactApplicationContext

Comment: I am not familiar with React, so is that an Application, Activity, Service, Broadcast ,... context?

Comment: @AliNaddaf looks like it is a service. I can use the activity here, but even if i use  

VideoCastManager.initialize(mCurrentActivity.getBaseContext(), options);

I receive the same error message

Comment: The exception is talking about main vs worker thread; are you calling that on a worker thread?

Comment: Oh, you're right. It should be inside a  runOnUiThread method right?

Comment: As long as it is is a Main/UI thread, that should be fine

Comment: that was the reason! thanks @AliNaddaf. Would you mind to post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is talking about main vs worker thread; are you calling that on a worker thread? If so, you should make some changes to call that on the main thread of your application.